# Impossible to connect to my postgreSQL Database

Tags: django, database, postgresql, docker, pgadmin

I'm using docker and I have started a new project.
I have a backend in Django and I want to use a postgreSQL Database.

I can't connect to my database with Django or with PGAdmin.
[This is what I Got when I try to connect to my database (with Django or with PGAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWCzH.png))

He is a part of my docker-compose file:

```
services:
db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db_wishlist
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./postgres-data-wishlist:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
        - env/base/db.env
        - env/dev/db.env
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    networks:
        wishlist:
            aliases:
                - db

pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin 
    depends_on:
        - db
    ports:
        - "5051:80"
    env_file:
        - env/base/db.env
        - env/dev/db.env
    environment:
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    restart: always
    networks:
        wishlist:
            aliases:
                - pgadmin

api:
    container_name: backend
    build:
        context: ..
        dockerfile: Docker/Dockerfiles/Django
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
        - ../Django/:/api
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
        - env/base/db.env
        - env/dev/db.env
    depends_on:
    - db
    links:
    - db:db
    networks:
        wishlist:
            aliases:
                - api
```

Here is my db.env:

```
POSTGRES_DB=wishlist
POSTGRES_USER=maxdal1
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=demo
```

Here is my settings.py in Django:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'wishlist',
    'USER': 'maxdal1',
    'PASSWORD': 'demo',
    'HOST': 'db',
    'PORT': 5432,
}
```

}

Here is an additional screenshot when I try to connect to my db with PGAdmin:

[Error with PGAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHm37.png)

I checked every discussion about this error but I can't figure it out.

Can you help me please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing your db user to postgres container via environment variable?

```
environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: "youruser"
```

Comment: Yes I already tried and it didn't work at all (same error)

Answer (score 0):

The following setup works for me:

docker-compose.yaml

```
services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - POSTGRES_DB=django_db
      - POSTGRES_USER=XXX
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXX
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:5432:5432
    networks:
      - backend

  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=django_db
      - POSTGRES_USER=XXX
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXX
    volumes:
      - ./staticfiles:/staticfiles
      - ./media:/media
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
```

settings.py

```
POSTGRES_HOST = os.environ.get('POSTGRES_HOST', 'localhost')
POSTGRES_DB = os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB', 'django_db')
POSTGRES_USER = os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER', 'XXX')
POSTGRES_PW = os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD', 'XXX')

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': POSTGRES_DB,
        'HOST': POSTGRES_HOST,
        'USER': POSTGRES_USER,
        'PASSWORD': POSTGRES_PW,
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 120,
    }
}
```

The Dockerfile for the django app specifies the following env vars:

```
ENV POSTGRES_DB=$POSTGRES_DB
ENV POSTGRES_HOST=$POSTGRES_HOST
ENV POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRES_USER
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
```

You can run this either like this:

```
$ docker-compose up
```

or only run the postgres via docker and run Django locally:

```
$ docker-compose up postgres
```

in a different terminal:

```
$ ./manage.py runserver
```

Comment: I changed everything to have something like you and I still get the same result... I d'ont understand

Comment: But it's strange because when I add manually the port in the database setting (5434 in my case), I get this error:
`"  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
backend    |    Is the server running on host "db" (172.26.0.2) and accepting
backend    |    TCP/IP connections on port 5434?"`

Comment: You are using some other IP, not the localhost 172.0.0.1 one. My setup is for local development.